# Select an png icon for Qt application executable

Tags: c++, qt

I am working with Qt to create a front-end for my application. Now I wanted to set an customized ICON for my application executable. I am using Qt 6.4. Already I create an resource file which it has .qrc format. Then I added my icon to that resource file. Now I wanted to know how can I set that icon file as executable icon. Is that possible somebody explain how can I set an customized icon for my application? Also I wanted to know how can I modify CMake to instruct compiler which executable should run with administrator privilege. Thank you.

Comment: <https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/appicon.html> seems to suggest that solution to your problem depends on target operating system that you totally failed to mention.

Comment: I am using Windows. This manual doesn't help me to set icon for the app. I need a well-defined and step-by-step instruct to set icon for the app.

Comment: You need to edit your question not give vital information in comments.

Answer (score 0):

Solution depends on your platform (Windows, mac, Linux) as well as your configuration tool (CMake, qmake).

Have a look at Qt documentation: https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/appicon.html. It tells what to do.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve that, in my side, I'm doing 2 things :

1.

```
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    a.setWindowIcon(QIcon(":/img/AppIcon.png"));
```

2. Create a `resource.rc` file with this content (have to possess a .ico version of the image)

```
IDI_ICON1               ICON    DISCARDABLE     "img/AppIcon.ico"
```

and declare in .pro

```
RC_FILE += \
    resource.rc
```